# array.splice shows strange behavior in Angular Js directive

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Checkout this plunkr
http://plnkr.co/edit/FQ7m6HPGRrJ80bYpH8JB?p=preview

In that After adding element when I delete element from array using splice method.
Everything gets messed up.

```
code
```

Comment: see my answer. you can see completely another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an object you hardcode the index of each new added object with you value of "abc"

```
var abc = 0;
$scope.addNode = function(){
    abc++;
    var addObj = {name:"name"+abc, index:abc};
    $scope.sitemap.push(angular.copy(addObj));
}
```

Then when you removing and calling function with this hardcoded value of index

```
$scope.removeNode = function(index){
    $scope.sitemap.splice(index,1);                     
}
```

So for example let say you have this array:

```
obj1 - hardcoded index 0 - array index 0
obj2 - hardcoded index 1 - array index 1
```

if remove obj1 from array with index 0 your obj2 will have index 0 in the array then,

```
obj2 - hardcoded index 1 - array index 0
```

but in your case you still passing to the removeNode function index 1 as it was created with that value.

Answer (score 3):

`Array.splice` needs an array index. The problem with your code is that you are passing the `ngModel.index` to the `removeNode` function and splicing an array with that `index` which is not actual array index.

You need to find the correct element index by looping through it and by checking its `index` property of each element. As I'm doing `angular.forEach` which seconds parameter gives us actual index of that array.

**Code**

```
    $scope.removeNode = function(index) {
      var foundIndex;
      angular.forEach($scope.sitemap, function(value, idx){
        if(value.index === index)
        foundIndex = idx;
      })

      $scope.sitemap.splice(foundIndex, 1);

    }
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/hq8lNJvd2kyd1OhP2xE5?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest another solution for that: [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview&s=0sOR2BUxImU0k1aX)

In my opinion:

- `sitemap` should not define in current directive(`sample`), because, it is list item(not list).
- Also, there is `addNode` method in your controller. there, `removeNode` should be declared.

You can access controller's method in directive through `removeAction: '&removeAction',`:

```
scope: {
    ngModel: "=ngModel",//or "="
    removeAction: '&removeAction',//or "&"
  },
  controller: ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.removeNode = function(item) {
      $scope.removeAction({
        item: item
      });
    }
  }],
```